# What's the difference between words "sort" and "destin"?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Are they basically interchangeable or do they have different meanings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are not always interchangeable. They can have the same meaning sometimes, but [*destin*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=destin) has a more positive aspect, while you would use [*sort*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=sort) to express a more negative meaning. You would notice the same difference in English when comparing *destiny* and *fate*.

*Sort* can also mean *spell* or *curse*, which is not the case of *destin*.

Also, in some idiomatic expressions, you will obviously have to use one and not the other, like in:

- *tirer au sort*
- *faire un sort (à quelque chose)*
- *c'est le destin!*

Comment: _fate_ and _destiny_ are AFAIK quite similar in meanings, far more than _sort_ and _destin_, even if we forget that one meaning of _sort_ is _spell_.

Comment: @Unfrancophone They are very similar in definition, but at least in colloquial usage they can mean very different things, depending on the context, e.g. *It was Harry Potter's destiny to vanquish Voldemort*, vs *Voldemort's fate was to die at the hand of Harry Potter*.

Comment: Bonne explication -- *fate* et *destiny*.

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of question, I recommend [this tool](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/fr/index_tr.html) which try to place English and French terms in a map even if it somewhat difficult to get used to it.  You'll see that *sort* has a wider set of meanings, mostly englobing the one of *destin*.

Where they are nearly substitutable, *sort* tend to gives an impression of randomness while *destin* suggest something more forecastable.

Comment: Très bon outil, +1!

Answer (score 3):

Destin is like destiny. Something that was written in a metal book by God and from which there is no way to escape (like death and tax).

Sort is more like a fate. Something that crossed you way, either by a malicious wizard or bad luck (mauvais sort) or by random (tiré au sort).

*A moins que ce sort n'ait été dans votre destin, il ne va pas durer.*

Comment: Belle citation, vous en êtes l'auteur ?